# Can't change the name form which the email is being sent

Tags: django, django-mailer

Here is the code that I am using

```
    subject = 'Opinion - OTP for login'
    message = 'Your OTP to login is {}'.format(callbacktoken)
    email_from = 'Opinion@noreply.com'
    # email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
    recipient_list = [email]
    send_mail(subject, message, email_from, recipient_list)
```

I expect the email to show Opinion@noreply.com as the name but they still show my email id that is in settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Does the email `Opinion@noreply.com` or the domain `noreply.com` belong to you? You can only send emails from email addresses that belong to you (or domains). Otherwise you cannot do that unless the appropriate DKIM and / or SPF records are set by the domain (`noreply.com`) allowing you to send emails from them.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Understood did not know that. I thought you could use any name. Others suggest it depends on the service gmail does not allow this

Answer (score 0):

You need to own the email, Sometimes email providers require to configure to allow sending emails through apps.

Comment: I found out that some providers like gmail do not allow name changing tho some do allow it. So email_from/from_email do not work if using gmail for sending mail.